# Amazon version of Rackspace's cloud sites?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rackspace-cloud

I was wondering if any of you know an Amazon version of cloud sites from rackspace. I know they have services similar to cloud servers and files but not this?

Basically, I'm looking for a scalable web server managed by them, *** but (this is what cloud sites can't do) I want to still be able to do things in the backend and install other apps etc.. (like my own server)?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon does not offer any managed hosting services. What they provide is infrastructure-as-a-service, the barebones level services for building on top of. They offer no management services. This stuff is meant for low level developers / system administrators to build the higher level systems on, not your average web hosting customer.

Comment: Both [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and [CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) can be used to distribute content via HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon's new [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) offers something closer to Rackspace Cloud Sites, but is currently limited to Java sites.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk now supports .Net and IIS: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a new Platform as a Service (SaaS) in the works to offer multiple languages/frameworks on top of AWS to the general public. Check it out...

http://www.mojoengine.com